# Reuse variable when unpacking and using auto

Tags: c++, c++17, c++20

I'm writing a little program for converting code from Go to C++20 ([go2cpp](https://github.com/xyproto/go2cpp)). Most of the code is relatively straightforward to convert, but I'm stuck on one particular case, where there is a name collision when unpacking a tuple.

Here's a complete example that can be saved as ie. `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <optional>
#include <tuple>

using namespace std::string_literals;
using error = std::optional<std::string>;

// convert a string to a double
// return both the double and an error (optional string)
// this must behave in a simiar fashion to strconv.ParseFloat in Go
auto strconvParseFloat(std::string s, int n) -> std::tuple<double, error>
{
    // n is ignored, for now
    try {
        return std::tuple { std::stod(s), std::nullopt };
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument& ia) {
        return std::tuple { 0.0, std::optional { "invalid argument"s } };
    }
}

// convert a string to an int
// return both the int and an error (optional string)
// this must behave in a simiar fashion to strconv.ParseInt in Go
auto strconvParseInt(std::string, int a, int n) -> std::tuple<int, error>
{
    return std::tuple { 0, std::optional { "not implemented"s } };
}

auto isNum(std::string s) -> bool
{
    auto [_0, err] = strconvParseFloat(s, 64);
    auto isFloat = (err == std::nullopt);
    auto [_1, err] = strconvParseInt(s, 0, 64);
    auto isInt = (err == std::nullopt);
    return isFloat || isInt;
}

auto main(int argc, char** argv) -> int
{
    const auto s = "3.14"s;
    //const auto s = "asdf"s;
    std::cout << s << " is a number: "s << std::boolalpha << isNum(s) << std::endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I compile it with GCC 10.2.0 using this command:

```sh
g++ -o main -std=c++2a -O2 -pipe -fPIC -fno-plt -fstack-protector-strong -Wall -Wshadow -Wpedantic -Wno-parentheses -Wfatal-errors -Wvla main.cpp
```

The error message I get is this:

```
main.cpp: In function ‘bool isNum(std::string)’:
main.cpp:36:15: error: conflicting declaration ‘auto err’
36 |     auto [_1, err] = strconvParseInt(s, 0, 64);
|               ^~~
```

If I rename the first `err` to `err1` and the second `err` to `err2`, the program compiles and runs just fine.

How can I force or otherwise convince the C++ compiler that the second use of `err` in `auto [_1, err]` is okay (like how it would be used in Go), and that I wish to redeclare `err`? Is there a compiler directive I can use, or perhaps `std::tie` in combination with `std::ignore` somehow?

I suspect that I have to use a namespace for this case, but would prefer to find another way that does not involve having to keep track of what goes into that block or not, when automatically converting code from Go.

Comment: I'm glad to see you're learning c++ :) In the future, make sure to always use the c++ tag in addition to the language version tags, more people will see your question that way.

Comment: @cigien, everyone using c++ are learning c++. :) I would not write code in a similar fashion if parts of it was not indented to be generated automatically, though. I'll remember to add a c++ tag in the future, not just c++17 and c++20.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just assumed you were primarily used to `go`based on the question. And you're absolutely right, there's always stuff to learn in c++ :)

Comment: You could consider an immediately invoked lambda function to initialise `isFloat` and `isInt`, making `_0/1` and `err` locals inside the lambda that don't leak to the function scope. Or even just do something like `const bool isFloat = !std::get<1>(strconvParseFloat(s, 64));`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, indeed you can use `std::tie` and `std::ignore` in the second call, like this:

```
std::tie(std::ignore, err) = strconvParseInt(s, 0, 64);
```

That's the only change required, you don't have to do anything with `namespace`s.

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/Ga3j8f).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but if I use that, I get `error: 'err' was not declared in this scope`. I am trying to avoid collecting all the variables and declaring them at the top of the function.

Comment: @Alexander Sounds like you changed the first call as well. Only change the second. I've added a demo.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to find something that will work with any number of `auto [_, err] = ...`, since it's being used in connection with automatically converting code from Go to C++.

Comment: Hmm, then you can either declare `err` at the top of the function, and transform every call consistently, or keep the first call, and transform everything else. I can't think of a way of transforming everything while also *not* declaring `err` prior.

Comment: Thanks, though. Perhaps some exotic `#pragma` can do it?

Comment: I'm very averse to using macros in c++. I don't know your exact use case, so maybe macros are ok. But try and make it a last resort :)